# How to read attribute value from xml file - FAKE F#MAKE

Tags: f#, f#-fake

Hi I am having an XML file , I want to read value of a particular attribute from XML file , how will I do this in FAKE . Please Help , I am new to F# and FAKE.And I just figured it out on fake documentation page and found that I can use XMLRead function of XMLHelper Class whose description is available at

```
https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/master/src/app/FakeLib/XMLHelper.fs#L14-14
```

But I could not understand how to do this , as there are no examples as such .

I have a huge XML file but for simplicity I am mentioning a piece of that file. XML File is as follows :

```
<version>
  <major number="2">
    <minor>1</minor>
    <build>1</build>
    <revised>1</revised>
  </major>
</version>
```

Please tell me , how to read values from mentioned attributes .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look back a few posts you can find a related question.
The short answer is that in my 'build.fsx' file I can do somthing like this:

```
// Build the main module with MSBuild
Target "BuildMain" (fun _ ->
  for s in XMLHelper.XMLRead true "./myxml.xml" "" "" "/version/major/minor"
   do trace s
  !! "./Kapoin_03_Main/Kapoin_03_Main.fsproj"
  |> MSBuild buildDir "Build" buildProps
  |> Log "Main build output: " )
```

That will in this case just write "1" in the console when you build.

Edit: If you are using a different target you may want to do something along the lines of the following to store a value as a variable:

```
let minver =
  XMLHelper.XMLRead
    true "./myxml.xml" "" "" "/version/major/minor"
  |> Seq.head
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for the effort , but what I am trying is to read values of attributes in another target ( not while building the solution ) or may be in another script. then i want to store those values in variables so that i can append those values in another .yaml files .

Comment: @johnfernandes, it would be better to update your question with the details of what you trying to do, rather than adding in the comments. That way anyone trying to help will not have to try and aggregate additional details through the comments.